# What is wrong with this code as I saw someone compile exact with no errors but I keep getting errors?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;
interface ERC20 {
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint256);
}
contract BalanceOracle {
    
    function exploreBalances(address[] calldata users) external view returns(uint256[] memory balances) {
        balances = new uint256[](users.length);
        for(uint i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            balances[i] = users[i].balance;
        }
    }
    
    function erc20Balances(address _token, address[] calldata users) external view returns(uint256[] memory balances) {
        ERC20 erc20 = ERC20(_token);
        balances = new uint256[](users.length);
        for(uint i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            balances[i] = erc20.balanceOf(users[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

ParserError: Expected ',' but got identifier
function erc20Balances(address[] _token, address calldata user) external view returns(uint256[] memory balances) {
^--^

Answer (score 0):

The `calldata` keyword was added at [Solidity 0.5.0](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/050-breaking-changes.html#syntax).

If you are compiling this contract with Solidity 0.4.X you have to remove it, and with 0.5.X you must add it as the 0.5.0 changelog states :

> Explicit data location for all variables of struct, array or mapping
> types is now mandatory. This is also applied to function parameters
> and return variables. For example, change uint[] x = m_x to

As a side node, your pragma shouldn't span across minor versions as those can introduce breaking changes (hence your question). [This answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/115382/rules-on-choosing-a-solidity-version) could be very informative for you.