# The state of the contract does not change

Tags: contract-debugging, geth-debugging, state-variable, state

I deployed the contract on my private *geth* network for testing.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.26;

contract MyContract {
    mapping (address => uint) private balances;

    function depositFunds() public payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
}
```

I called the *depositFunds* function and ETH was transferred.

```
> myinstance.depositFunds({from:'0x2476b5bf267aba5c9b4bff499863e8ae5e39564c', value: 13333})
> eth.getBalance(myinstance.address)
13333
```

However, the state of the contract has not changed.

```
> eth.getStorageAt(myinstance.address, 0)
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: I am not sure but could you try this --> eth.getStorageAt(Mycontract.address, 0) I think storage changed for your's contract address, not your account that received ETH

Comment: Isn't the contract address permanent?

Comment: You are just reading the wrong storage slot. Please read this to learn about mappings layout in contract storage : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/115382/rules-on-choosing-a-solidity-version . You have to read slot keccak256(h(k) . p) where h(k) is the address you want to read in balances padded to 32 bytes and p is the value 0 (for the slot of your mapping declaration : storage slot 0)

Comment: @hroussille, please correct me if I am wrong. If the contract had only one variable of type value, then the method above would return the value of the variable, correct? I did it once (getStorage(address, 0)) and it returned me the value of the variable, as expected.

Comment: You are correct, but mappings are not value types, they are reference types. Please see my answer explaining storage layout of mappings and how to access them through `getStorageAt` (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/114186/how-does-ethereum-fit-a-mapping-into-storage/114206#114206) , Long story short, you need to read storage slot 0xd1552d9b9a211afb39ba81aeb6779bf0f57a902c6da8b4bc43342834917cbe70 tell me if I did a mistake of if something is not clear enough from the answer I linked

Comment: the slot I gave you is only valid to get the balance of a user with address 0x2476b5bf267aba5c9b4bff499863e8ae5e39564c from a mapping declared at storage slot 0.

Comment: Btw, I just realized that my first comment "You are just..." contains the wrong link... I meant https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/internals/layout_in_storage.html#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays and not this unrelated answer that I included, sorry.